# MVC4: Add and remove items to list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have some trouble to add and remove items in my list collections. I use MVC 4, Razor.

Have found some examples, but it based on jquery and javascript - can MVC not do it alone?
I want to be add buildings, and some floors to the buildings - and also remove items again.

House.cs

```
public class House
{
    public House()
    {
        Buildings = new List<HouseBuilding>();
    }

    public List<HouseBuilding> Buildings { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }
    public String RoofType { get; set; }
}
```

HouseBuilding.cs

```
public class HouseBuilding
{
    public HouseBuilding()
    {
        Floors = new List<HouseBuildingFloor>();
    }

    public List<HouseBuildingFloor> Floors { get; set; }
    public Int32 BuildingNo { get; set; }
    public Int32 SquareMeters { get; set; }

    public Boolean Deleted { get; set; }
    public String DeletedClass
    {
        get
        {
            if (Deleted)
            {
                return "containerHidden";
            }
            else
            {
                return "containerVisible";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HouseBuildingFloor.cs

```
public class HouseBuilding
{
    public HouseBuilding()
    {
        Floors = new List<HouseBuildingFloor>();
    }

    public List<HouseBuildingFloor> Floors { get; set; }
    public Int32 BuildingNo { get; set; }
    public Int32 SquareMeters { get; set; }

    public Boolean Deleted { get; set; }
    public String DeletedClass
    {
        get
        {
            if (Deleted)
            {
                return "containerHidden";
            }
            else
            {
                return "containerVisible";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you are talking about adding stuff with razor, jquery or javascript yet you are showing some model code. Is this question about implementing the UI to achieve this?

Comment: The problem is i cant add items to the class (model) in UI. I have created views to edit/show the model, but i cant figure out how to add items. Better? :)